How to remove side-by-side spacing in Snackbar in MAUI?
There's a default side-by-side spacing in MAUI Snackbar using the community toolkit, and I'm looking to remove it. Any insights on how to achieve that?
var snackbarOptions = new SnackbarOptions
{
    BackgroundColor = Colors.Black,
    TextColor = Colors.White,
    ActionButtonTextColor = _themeColor,              
    CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(0),
    Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(_fontSize),
};


Maybe show a screenshot of the problem, this will help others understand what you mean.

To remove the default side-by-side spacing in the MAUI Snackbar, set both ActionButtonTextColor and ActionButton properties to null in your SnackbarOptions object. This will remove the action button and the spacing associated with it.

From the official document Snackbar,we could find that there is only a property CharacterSpacing  for setting message character spacing. There are no other properties to set the spacing. But you can try to set CornerRadius  to a value greater than 0 which will make the UI better.
var snackbarOptions = new SnackbarOptions
{
    BackgroundColor = Colors.Black,
    TextColor = Colors.White,
    ActionButtonTextColor = _themeColor,      
    
    CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(14),
    Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(_fontSize),

    CharacterSpacing = 0 //Message character spacing
};

For your problem, you can create a new Featurehere. Thanks for your feedback.
Besides,you can also create a custom Snackbar yourself.Then you can define the layout yourself. For this,you can check article:.NET MAUI: Display Custom Snackbar from ViewModels.
